# Dynamically updating question view counter

Tags: feature-request, views, live-refresh

Most posts update on-the-fly as changes are made, but question view counts still require a page refresh.

Whenever I ask a question, I usually find myself refreshing the page compulsively, to find out whether it's getting attention. If the view counter was dynamic, I wouldn't have to do that.

I would like view counts to be updated dynamically along with the other content.

Comment: You should probably indicate that it would refresh the page views every, say, five minutes.  If you did it every time the value changed, then that's a lot of notifications on the back end (on a site with millions of page views a day) and possibly a ton of notifications to the front end in a short period of time.  Having a rate-limited window on this is an absolute must.

Comment: How do comments/edits/answers do it? Are they rate-limited too?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the thing is, comments and answers flow in *much* less frequently than views on a page.  So sending out a single notification whenever the page view counter ticks up by one is going to saturate the network pretty quick.

Comment: I do the same (reload page to update the counter) and it causes the counter to increase by one, which is undesired. Maybe an extra "update counter" button (that appears when pointing/hovering over the counter - to avoid page clutter)?

Comment: @DavidBalažic your views aren't counted, if the counter increased by one when you refreshed it probably means that someone else viewed the question

Comment: @Motti Strange, everytime I refresh (except if done very fast), it increments by one. Never by two or more (well, very rarely). I doubt there is always exactly one other user viewing my question between refreshes. (obviously, if I wait a day then refresh, it would increase by more, I am talking about the case when I refresh every minute or so)

Comment: This has been officially declined in a dupe.