# "Currently Reading" list on network questions

Tags: feature-request

Some people, like me, stalk their own questions and constantly hit refresh to see the amount of views my question has received.

**A.** It would be nice for this to do an ajax update so you wouldn't need to refresh.

**B.** It would be nice to have an "actively reading" section to see who's currently on your question and reading it instead of people who viewed it.

I think this would be somewhat of a help to those interested in tracking who's actually reading their question and who is just taking a glimpse and running a way. It would also encourage title changes and post updates to kind of increase the chances of getting more viewers so your question reaches out to more people.

Comment: First part is [already requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181697/dynamically-updating-question-view-counter), second request here fits a social network, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: No way should B be implemented. Anything social-media-ish would be a major turn off and I value private viewing of questions and answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to see # users currently viewing a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146846/way-to-see-users-currently-viewing-a-question)

Comment: If you can see who is on the page, and then you see the votes change, you're going to have a better idea on who voted how

Comment: Well I guess I asked the wrong question for my first time on the meta site.

Answer (score 4):

People have already made some great points in comments, but I think there're a few major issues with this, not the least of which being that it doesn't really add anything *useful*. Curiosity is all well and good, but there are more important things that the developers at Stack Exchange can do with their time. Seeing who's on your post might satisfy an excitement of "hooray! attention!," but it won't help you find a question or an answer, and those are what Stack Exchange is fundamentally about.

On top of that, there's another philosophical issue: listing "currently viewing" brings a focus on users, which is pretty rare in the Stack Exchange world. In general, there's a preference to emphasize *content*. Users are listed and attributed for their content, but the focus needs to be on that. Pop over to the /users page of your favourite site: it's the only way (that I can think of, at least) to see users *without* starting at their content, and even there, there's an emphasis on reputation, reputation per time, and how much a person helps the site through votes or edits. You can't just "view all users by alphabet" because that wouldn't be useful. In this scenario, with users' views showing in real-time, that puts an emphasis on them and not their content, since they presumably aren't writing any content.

The only way to make this useful, I think, and I believe this has already been discussed elsewhere, is showing a count (numbers only) of how many answers are currently being written, just so twenty people don't jump in to say the exact same thing. But ultimately, even that wouldn't bring a ton of value.

[Random said this in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243105/currently-reading-list-on-network-questions/243122#comment794654_243105), too, but I also think it's worth noting: this would also take away some precious anonymity from votes, especially on questions that aren't getting viewed much. The more down-votes a question gets, the angrier the user behind it gets, and the fewer people who will bother to click into it (in theory), so there could be some quite unfortunate consequences with letting users see who's viewing a question, even on top of the philosophical issues I've mentioned before.